# Generating $n$ random samples every time

Tags: random

Is it possible to generate $n$ random samples, and always ensure that $n$ samples are generated?

eg For $n=5$:

```
n=5; {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5} = (While[Total[set = Reverse@Sort@Round
[(tmp = RandomInteger[100, n])/Total@tmp 100]] != 100]; set);
s = Reverse[Sort[{n1, n2, n3, n4, n5}]];
a = rs[[1]]; b = s[[2]]; c = s[[3]]; d = s[[4]]; e = s[[5]];
PieChart[{a, b, c, d, e}, ImageSize -> 200, 
ChartLabels -> {Style[StringForm["A:``%", a], 10], 
Style[StringForm["B:``%", b], 10], 
Style[StringForm["C:``%", c], 10], 
Style[StringForm["D:``%", d], 10], 
Style[StringForm["E:``%", e], 10]}]
```

is ok, but for large enough $n$ the numbers are often "used up" before the last few get a chance to sample (so, in the example of the above pie chart, "E" often doesn't feature).

Is it possible to avoid the samples reaching $0$ before last $n$ is reached? (Obviously, by the time $n=100$, each sample should have value of $1$.)

Comment: This is very unclear. There is no $n$ in your code.

Comment: Question edited accordingly.

Comment: If your summed value (100 in your example) and n are not too large you could use `RandomSample[IntegerPartitions[100, 5], 1]`. However, do take care as `IntegerPartitions` can blow up extremely fast and fill up all of your memory (potentially crashing your kernel) if you're not cautious.

Comment: Great - thank you - will give it a go :)

Comment: So you are trying to create a list of n random integers such that `Total[list]==100` and `Min[list]==1` ?

Comment: Yes - pretty much - actually, there is no reason why 2 or more of the partitions couldn't be the same (as long as they totalled 100) - which wouldn't be the case if sample were used, I suppose.

Comment: I also do not know whether the distribution of the drawings is what you need. You didn't specify that.

Comment: Yes - would be good ideally

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries `{5}`. Also, you can use `RandomChoice`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Partitioning `n` into `k` elements

Here's a way to efficiently use the logic of partitioning from my first attempt (which can be found in the edit history).

Imagine slicing the ordered set of integers at k-1 distinct places between integers 1 and n-1.  Then we simply evaluate the size of each slice (in terms of the number of integers contained in the respective interval).

A suggestion by Simon Woods helped streamline the code.

```
g[n_,k_]:=Differences@Join[{0},Sort@RandomSample[Range[n-1],k-1],{n}]
```

**Examples**

```
g[100, 5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000068, {16, 26, 13, 16, 29}}

---

```
g[100, 15] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@%[[2]]
```

> {0.000052, {5, 28, 7, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 12, 3, 1, 11, 9, 4, 3}}
>   100

---

```
g[100, 35] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@%[[2]]
```

> {0.000063, {1, 1, 6, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 8, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 
>     1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 2, 12, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3}}
>   100

---

```
g[997, 55] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@%[[2]]
```

> {0.000065, {20, 29, 72, 10, 4, 13, 43, 42, 9, 12, 1, 19, 10, 1, 9, 22,
>      63, 8, 9, 42, 8, 11, 27, 3, 8, 16, 18, 33, 23, 1, 33, 30, 1, 4, 49,
>      24, 1, 1, 6, 31, 2, 4, 23, 8, 32, 12, 9, 6, 39, 2, 13, 1, 39, 4, 
>     37}}
>   997

Comment: +1 This must be the most efficient approach I think. You could write the output more succinctly as `Differences@Join[{0}, slices, {n}]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggested shortening of code, which I will incorporate.

Answer (score 7):

If the problem is to create a list of $n$ random integers such that `Total[list]==100` and `Min[list]>=1`, how about starting with a list of $n$ ones (taking care of the `Min[list] >= 1` criterion) and then incrementing a random element of the list $100-n$ times.

```
n = 50;
list = ConstantArray[1, n];
Scan[list[[#]]++ &, RandomInteger[{1, n}, 100 - n]];

Reverse @ Sort @ list    
(* {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)

Total @ list
(* 100 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - very much appreciated :)